# Unable to Switch to iframe in IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

Code Trails:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
List<WebElement> before = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));

for (WebElement t : before) {
    System.out.println("iframe" + t.getAttribute("src"));
}

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'srcpath')]")));
List<WebElement> after = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
for (WebElement t : after) {
 System.out.println("iframe" + t.getAttribute("src"));
 if(t.getAttribute("src").equalsIgnoreCase("expectedsrc")){
    System.out.println("success");
    break;                              
  }
}
```

Before Switching to iframe (let's say **abc**), iframes above **abc** were printed which is correct. But after switching, it prints the **same iframes**. But actually there are different iframes inside the 'abc' iframe. So after switching to abc, it should print iframes which are only inside abc or along with abc iframes.

I didn't get any `NoSuchFrameException` while switching which makes it clear that I have switched to the `Iframe`.

IFrames doesnot have `id`, `class`, `name` attributes, but `src`.

But When I print the PageSource of abc iframe, it prints only the html source of abc iframe.

```
String pagesrc = driver.switchTo()
        .frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'srcpath')]"))).getPageSource();
```

Funny, the same code works in Chrome and FF.

**Configuration**:
IEDriverServer: 3.12.0
IEBrowser: IE9
Jar : Selenium 3.4.0
JDK : 1.8

Html Source: [Source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJFc9BGBDYvfMVsgOmSGPlSoZIT8idLL/view?usp=sharing)